# how to convert json string to object in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

Its been a day scratching my head & googling on how to convert json string to an object.

This is my json.

```
   {
"statusCode": 200,
"data": {
"items": [
  {
    "id": 2623,
    "JsonData": "{\"Number\":143,\"IsDeleted\":false,\"GapAnalysisChecked\":false,\"ShowGraphics\":true,\"Impact\":{\"Value\":\"DefaultNodeTitle_Impact\",\"Details\":null,\"DefaultValue\":\"DefaultNodeTitle_Impact\",\"Id\":\"0a507b25-cf0f-4ee3-8262-76b29adbda4e\"},\"Gap\":{\"Value\":\"DefaultNodeTitle_Gap\",\"Details\":null,\"DefaultValue\":\"DefaultNodeTitle_Gap\",\"Id\":\"cd411a47-a215-4dda-a8af-19686ad0d090\"}"}]
}
```

}

I am in need to convert JsonData to a single object.

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(res.JsonData);
res.JsonData = obj; //this is giving error.- Cannot convert implicilty string to an object
```

Along with it, I have tried with number of permutatiation like `DeserializeObject<Customer>()` & all such things.

My desired output.

```
{
"statusCode": 200,
"data": {
"items": [
  {
    "id": 2623,
    "JsonData": object
}
```

MY DTO

```
public class Res
{
  public string StatusCode {get;set;}

  public string JsonData {get; set;}
}
```

Any help/suggestion highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: `//this is giving error.` isn't descriptive.. What error?

Comment: @ColinM, addded

Comment: Without seeing your code, `res.JsonData = (object)obj;` ?

Comment: `{
"statusCode": 200,
"data": {
"items": [
  {
    "id": 2623,
    "JsonData": object
}]}` this is valid JSON

Comment: @MANISHKUMARCHOUDHARY, sorry!! I didn't get you

Comment: Your JSON is not valid because you miss `]}`

Comment: I put a simple implementation of that

Answer (score 9):

You're missing "]"

**EDIT**

One possible implementation would be something like this :

Your classes

```
public class Res{

   public string statusCode {get;set;}
   public Data data {get; set;}


}


 public class Data{

  public List<Item> items {get; set;}

  }


 public class Item{

    public string id {get; set;}
    public JsonData JsonData {get;set;}

}

 public class JsonData{

    public string name {get; set;}
    public string from {get; set;}
 }
```

Your json

```
{
"statusCode":200,
"data" :
     {
       "items" :
           [
             {
              "id":2623,
              "JsonData" :{
               "name":"joab",
               "from":"Brazil"}
               },
               {
               "id":2624,
               "JsonData": {
               "name":"mary",
               "from":"USA"
               }
             }
          ]
     }
}

var res = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Res>(yourjson);
```

Comment: Corrected the json string

Comment: added the class

Answer (score 0):

1 - Add new class 
2 - Copy your json 
3 - Visual Studio Menu > Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON as Classes

[See](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGXWU.png)